# IPython with bpython features

Tags: python, ipython, bpython

I really admire bpython with its nice coloring and autocomplete, autohint and so on.

The problem is, there are some features in IPython which I can't do without, for example, reload, magic commands, matplotlib interacting, the shell interaction, the Vim interaction or the IPython notebook. I know there is also autocomplete in IPython, but it's not as nice as in bpython.

Is there a way to put bpython in IPython?

---

Checkout this: http://bipython.org/

Comment: IPython [is interested](http://wiki.ipython.org/Potential_projects) in someone doing a bpython-like frontend, perhaps using code from bpython. If you've got time to work on it, people on the mailing list will be happy to provide more information.

Comment: ah that's a nice information, thank you thomas

Comment: For now bipython seams like a dirty hack but very promising! Thank you for your edit!

Answer (score 1):

I was using bpython and IPython until I found out about [DreamPie](http://dreampie.sourceforge.net/).