# Pydocs in iPython similar to bpython

Tags: python, shell, ipython, pydoc, bpython

Is there a way to do inline pydocs in iPython the same way it works in bpython.

bpython screenshots from their site: 
[image: bpython xrange docs]
[image: bpython os pydocs]

Comment: Just in case you missed it - it's not as good as bpython's interactive hints, but you can append '?' or '??' to any method call, press enter and get the docs and implementation.

Comment: Hmm I saw that but is there no way to script the functionality? The strengths of both programs would be ideal to have in one program.

Comment: There was another question about this recently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444956/ipython-with-bpython-features . We would like someone to do a bpython-like frontend for IPython, perhaps using code from bpython. Ask on the mailing list for details if you're interested in having a go.

Comment: @ThomasK: Make what you said an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest [**bipython**](http://bipython.org/). It works like if Ipython have an implementation of bpython. You'll need to call `bipython` within the `Ipython console`.

I would suggest that you to ask any issue about bipython to their [github](https://github.com/ivanov/bipython/issues).

Comment: I'm actually changed my workflow to use IPython Notebooks which has all the features I want plus a really convenient way to share my work with friends. I no longer work in the shell directly, just a protected hosted IPython Notebook.

Notebook has inline docs, color-coding, and the advantage of writing Markdown comments to explain the code.

Comment: Usually I found that when someone asking for an implementation of bpython in Ipython they end up switching to Ipython Notebooks completly and tend to use bpython for the more so basic/quick stuff. Switching for Ipython proves your maturity in python.

Answer (score 1):

[Related] Another quite interesting python console: http://dreampie.sourceforge.net/